# O operador "==" não pode ser aplicado a operadores do tipo "string" e "long"

Tags: c#, operadores

Olá, boa noite.
Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade em C# e não tenho muita experiência. Fui rodar o programa e o erro descrito no título apareceu.
O pedaço do código é esse:

```
public Produto BuscarProdutoPorCodigo(long codigoProduto)
    {
        return this.Produtos
                   .Where(produto => produto.Id == codigoProduto)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void RemoverProdutoPorCodigo(long codigoProduto)
    {
        this.Produtos.Remove(this.Produtos
                   .Where(produto => produto.Id == codigoProduto)
                   .FirstOrDefault());
        Salvar();
    }
```

Já tentei converter para "Int32", etc, mas não funcionou.
Alguém consegue me ajudar? Obrigada.

Comment: Produto.Id é qual tipo?

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque a propriedade `Id` do produto é uma `string` e o parâmetro passado `codigoProduto` é `long` e você não pode comparar um número com um texto.

Nessa situação, você pode passar como parâmetro uma string, uma vez que a `Id` do produto vai ser sempre uma string:

```
public Produto BuscarProdutoPorCodigo(string codigoProduto)
{
    return this.Produtos
               .Where(produto => produto.Id == codigoProduto)
               .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Leitura recomendada: [Tipos e variáveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables)

Comment: Meu Deus, eu jurava que tinha colocado string também. Agora funcionou.
Obrigada!

Comment: Por nada, acesse o [Tour] e bem vinda a comunidade.